# How to change the classes of multiple divs each after a time period in React

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I've just learned React and I'm a making a Simon game as a first practice app. I'm having trouble getting the divs to "light up" one after another, after a time period.

In [this code](https://codesandbox.io/s/gracious-brown-kr9wmb), in my Cube component, I am attempting to iterate through a test array (computerMoves), and for each move to "light up" one of the divs by adding the class "on" (increase in brightness) for a second.

The desired result is to see side1 lighten for 1 second and then turn off, then the same for side 2, then the same for side 3. The result I am getting is I am only seeing this happen for side 3.

Where am I going wrong?

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/gracious-brown-kr9wmb)

Comment: Can you provide a working codesandbox link that illustrates your problem, making sure to include the relevant CSS as well?  I can see some issues with your code, but I don't currently see how it can cause the exact problem you are describing, and want to make sure we are on the same page.

Comment: I got it to run: https://codesandbox.io/s/gracious-brown-kr9wmb  - Does this help clarify?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One issue with your implementation is that when you first render your cube, you are setting all three cube sides to "on" and starting all three timers at the same time.  Then, after ~1 second, all three timers are popping, and removing the "on" class from all three cube sides.  So I would expect your implementation first highlight all 3 sides simultaneously, and then de-highlight them after 1 second.  Another issue is that for whatever reason, the brightness filter is only really producing a visible change on the green, and not on the red or blue (it IS being applied though).

The simplest way to change your code is something [like this](https://codesandbox.io/s/musing-galois-i1x5n5?file=/src/App.js), which is just adding some timers to make things happen in "the right order".  I also updated the cubes sides to use `opacity` differences for highlighting, rather `filter: brightness`.

[Here is a codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-allen-obnevr?file=/src/App.js) with a different strategy, accomplishing the same overall thing but enforcing a strict sequence of events.  I also took some liberties and restructured your `sides` to be zero-indexed.

I think the second solution may be a little easier to extend if you end up adding additional faces to the cube, or want to have more than 3 moves.

Comment: I see the difference now. The first version is just a bunch of timers, each one getting progressively longer so the sides end up blinking in a sequence. You are right, this is not what I wanted at all. Your way (the second one) is significantly better for all the reasons you described. I ended up adding a timeout in the if condition within unblinkSide so that a same side flashing after itself (e.g. [...0, 0...]) will blink on/off twice rather blinking immediately after a blink and appearing to stay on for twice as long. Thanks, this has helped me greatly.